# Best way to monitor for SSL / Connection failures on a server that's still up

Tags: linux, nginx, monitoring, ssl-certificate-errors

We had an outage issue today (NGinx not successfully restarted by our Let's Encrypt renewal CRON job, so not serving the renewed cert) leading to the server being up according to Pingdom but not serving the web service it should have been. Is there a way of monitoring for unsuccessful connection / page serving rather than whatever Pingdom is currently measuring (server response?)? We've been looking at Rollbar for exception monitoring too - can either of these services track / monitor for this kind of problem?

Comment: Check for the HTTP Status code, probably `200`. Or some content you expect.

Comment: @gf_ thanks - which service were you recommending that check to originate from?

Answer (score 1):

You can use check_http which is a plugin for Nagios or Icinga.
When run from cron you should append something like `| grep -v OK` to only get output/mail when it is not Ok.

https://www.monitoring-plugins.org/doc/man/check_http.html

It even supports checking the remaining days of validity for the certificate.

Comment: this sounds like it's worth looking into - thanks